# Show data from database in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, show, src

I want to show data from database into ajax.

```css
function Data_Table() {
  $.ajax( {
    url: "<?php echo site_url('admin-spot/company/FieldTable')?>", type: "GET", dataType: "JSON", success: function(data) {
      $('#map').dataSrc(data.map);
    }
  }
  );
}
```

```html
<iframe id="map" src="" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Why you using an iframe for datatables?

Comment: what is in data.map

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam, map is field database

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone i use frame because i wan to show google map link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="demon";
    
    //CREATE CONNECTION
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    //CHECK CONNECTION
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("connection failed:".$conn->connect_error);
    }       
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ul li</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <?php
        $result=$conn->query("select * from category");
        while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        { 
            //print_r($row);
            //die();
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <?php echo $row["CATEGORY_ID"]; ?>  
                <?php echo $row["CATEGORY_NAME"]; ?>
            </li>
        </ul>       
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand from your hard to judge description and the comments section, you are trying to set the `src` attribute of the `iframe` 
 with the googlemap link in the ajax `success` function and the `src` is coming from server-side, if this is it you have to use `.prop` to assign the src  which should be a URL

change your function to the following

```
 function Data_Table() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('admin-spot/company/FieldTable')?>",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {

                $('#map').prop('src',
                    data.map
                );
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .load() method here the jquery API [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

## Javascript

Use simple

```
$("#result").load("ajax/test.html");
```

or with a callback

```
$("#result").load("ajax/test.html", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand. because i get data from database, and where should i write a field table from database

Comment: You can load your site page in a `div`. if you need an iframe you can use `$('#myiframe').attr('src', 'myurl.php')`